# What is the maximum data size when querying BI tool called chartio from the query of BigQuery data?

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the maximum data size when querying BI tool called [Chartio](https://chartio.com/) from the query of BigQuery data?

Is the amount of data stored in BigQuery unlimited?

Comment: Could you clarify what the main question is? Are you asking on limitation on query size for BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

There is no storage limit, however, there is a [monthly fee](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#pricing_summary) for each GB stored:

- first 10GB are [free](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#free-tier-storage)
- everything after that is 0.02$
- if the table is not edited for [90 days](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#long-term-storage) than monthly price is 0.01$ for that table.

Look at BigQuery's [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing) and [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) for more information.